# object files need to be placed in different directory

Tags: c++, makefile

I would appreciate if anyone could help me with the Makefile error.  I would like to compile a C++ application into a shared library and place the compiled object `*.o` files in `./sobjs` directory like below. I followed several examples to do this, however I still have the problem to get this correct compilation and linker.

Makefile:

```
OBJS = a1.o a2.o a3.o a4.o a5.o

objects = sobj/$(OBJS)

all: $(objects)
        $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) $(objects) -shared -o libname.so

$(objects) : | sobjs

sobjs:
        @mkdir -p $@

sobjs/%.o: %.cpp
        @echo $<
        $(CXX) -fPIC -c -o $@ $< $(CXX_FLAGS) $(MY_FLAGS) $(INCLUDE_DIRS)
```

Comment: What is the error?  A message, or incorrect results?

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake. Replace this

```
objects = sobj/$(OBJS)
```

with this

```
objects = $(patsubst %.o, sobjs/%.o,$(OBJS))
```

and it will now compile files correctly.

Comment: @SagarSakre: users cannot accept their own answer to their question until 48 hours after the question was asked.